# Ubuntu installed on an external hard disk but not working

Tags: boot

I have installed Ubuntu on my external hard disk (1TB Western Digital, My Passport). I have only 30GB of free space in my external hard disk, so I partitioned as:

- 1st partition is for my backup data which is of around 900GB
- 2nd partition is for Ubuntu, which is of 30GB, in which i have made sub-partitions using GParted

For that, I have already have Ubuntu setup in my USB drive of 2GB, which I created using universal USB installer. The sub-partition is like:

```
/boot - 512MB
/ - 20GB
swap - 4GB
/home - rest space left in that 30GB
```

Now I have completely installed Ubuntu with the help of pendrive of 2GB in `/` partition. And, boot loader in `/boot`.

When I restart my computer, it is straightly loading Windows. Then, I searched for the problem here and tried many things such as booting from an external drive active in boot menu. Pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>. But the Ubuntu boot is not appearing and the computer directly loads the Windows installed in my internal hard disk. I have a Sony laptop.

How can I boot Ubuntu?

Comment: Would reinstalling Ubuntu be an issue? Try going through the set-up again, except when it says "where to install bootloader" don't select boot partition. Instead, just choose /dev/sdX where X is the letter you are installing to. For example is / is /dev/sdc1 and /boot is /dev/sdc2, choose just /dev/sdc (no number). It's what I did to boot from a 64gb pen drive with a separate NTFS partition to be shared between systems.

Comment: Ok, I am going to try it as per your suggestion.....This means that to install boot loader in the external hard disk not in any of the partition. Right?

Comment: Yeah. For some reason not selecting a partition helped me boot when I had more than one partition going on. Don't fully understand logic behind it.

Comment: Comment in chat confirmed what I thought was going on. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are installing to an external drive, you need to configure the bootloader to be in the MBR of the drive itself. As such, you do not want to choose the `/boot` partition for the installation target of the bootloader.

Instead, select the bootloader installation target as `/dev/sdX`, replacing X with which ever letter the rest of your partitions are under. `/dev/sda` is usually the hard drive, so you normally don't want that. Since you are using a USB drive to install and a USB drive as the target, you will see `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`. Choose the one that is the external drive. Please not that the letters can show up in any order and can be associated with any drive, so look carefully.

This will make it so that the drive now has a valid bootloader. If there is no loader in the MBR, the computer does not know how to load. For example, when I was running install on a pen drive, I had three partitions. `/`, `/home`, and `/storage`, where `/storage` was a NTFS partition to be shared between Windows and Ubuntu. `/` was `/dev/sdc1`, `/home`, was `/dev/sdc2`, and so on. I had the Ubuntu installer point to just `/dev/sdc` when installing GRUB so that the drive itself would be receiving the install, rather than one of the partitions.